# GetData From IsolatedStorage without Restriction

Tags: c#, wpf, isolatedstorage

I try to test isolated storage for an wpf application et i want to can getData et InsertData from two applications for the same isolatedStorage. I try different getStore(...), but no work.

```
 IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Machine | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);


private static void LoadData()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Machine | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);

        if (isoStore.GetFileNames(filename).Length == 0)
        {
            // File not exists. Let us NOT try to DeSerialize it.        
            return;
        }

        // Read the stream from Isolated Storage.    
        Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore);
        if (stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // DeSerialize the Dictionary from stream.            
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Dictionary<string, Object> appData = (Dictionary<string, Object>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

                // Enumerate through the collection and load our Dictionary.            
                IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = appData.GetEnumerator();
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    appDictionary[enumerator.Key.ToString()] = enumerator.Value;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Regards,
Matthieu

Comment: Why not just use it like it was supposed to be used? Also, please provide the code that you tried to fix your problem and tell us what went wrong with it.

Comment: I use isolated storage with the normal use. what do you mean? When i launch two instance of the same app with isolated gestion. If i add and save data from one, the second can't get the new data and i don't know what i need to do to make it work.

Comment: My answer explains what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you were to read up about the technology that you were using, you would understand why you can't access another user's data... the clue is in the name: Isolated Storage. From the [Types of Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh5d60e1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Access to isolated storage is always restricted to the user who created it.
>   ...
>
> By combining the concepts of user, domain, and assembly identity, isolated storage can isolate data in the following ways, each of which has its own usage scenarios:
>
> • Isolation by user and assembly
>   • Isolation by user, domain, and assembly

For more information, please see the [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.